# Replace one column with another based on 3rd column of same table in SQL

Tags: java, sql, spring-mvc

I am having a table and for one column of table I need to replace its value wherever not `null` with the value in another column  based on the value which it is having matched with again another column of same table.

Means say I am having table `t1` with primary key `c1`:

```
  c1       c2         c3
--------------------------
1          a           null
23         b           null
2          c             1
```

So I want my result as:

```
  c1         c2            c3
------------------------------
1             a           null
23            b           null
2             c             a   ---->(means the  1 in column c3 is replaced by column c2's 
                                       value whose c1's value is 1)
```

Comment: 1) Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form. 2) You've described a problem, but have so far not asked a question (let alone a specific, answerable question).  What *is* your question?  If it might be summed up as *"How to replace one column with another based on 3rd column of same table in SQL?"* then please [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17894238/edit) to include that.

Comment: Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: What you are trying to do is called a self-join.  You join a table to itself as if you had two separate tables containing exactly the same data.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
update t1 set y.c3 = x.c2
from t1 x inner join t1 y on x.c1 = y.c3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.c1,t.c2,(SELECT a.c2 FROM t1 a WHERE a.c1=t.c3) FROM t1 t
```